# Just updated to Android studio 2.1 Beta and freezez on build.gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

This is the version I updated (just appeared today 14 April)[image]

And now It remains stuck in gradle build.
in my aps config the app just changed:
From:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0-alpha5'
```

to:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0-beta1'
```

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Using:    ./gradlew assembleDebug

I saw it gets stuck at:

```
  > Building 7% > :libraries:facebook:mergeReleaseProguardFiles
```

with:

```
 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Timeout waiting to lock task history cache   (/Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/.gradle/2.10/taskArtifacts). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.
Owner PID: 858
Our PID: 1149
Owner Operation: Load task history
Our operation: Load task history
Lock file: /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/.gradle/2.10/taskArtifacts/cache.properties.lock

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

PS: after deleting cache.properties.lock, it worked, once. and now it works from time to time, but I keep getting this issue:

```
 Error:Execution failed for task ':passenger:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
 > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:           com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this to gradle.properties fixed it:
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=4096m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError